# Selenium IDE format for Jenkins integration

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, selenium-ide

My goal is to have a test created in Selenium IDE and then exported to run headlessly in Jenkins.

What is the proper configuration needed so this can be done as seamlessly as possible?

Comment: Not sure if you can do it with Selenium IDE. Have a read here. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/headless-functional-testing-with-selenium-and-phantomjs--net-30545

Answer (score 2):

Its should be like this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144744/how-do-i-launch-the-selenium-ide-from-the-command-line-with-a-specific-test-case

Read the above question and create a bat file to execute your selenium IDE via command promt.

Then use that bat file onside your jenkins project to invoke selenium test.